# Change view controller when user exits app

Tags: ios, swift

Hey I am trying to make it so whenever the user presses the home button and then try to returns to my app, they are returned to the initial view controller. Is there anything I can write into the app delegate to get this to work?

I have tried to call this function in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` function:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let VC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeVC") as! UIViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But i get an error saying the view is not in the hierarchy.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to implement the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method of your App's delegate, and programmatically perform a segue or dismiss the current view controller, depending on the navigation setup.

Your users might not like forced navigation though. The general assumption is that they can resume where they left off.

Comment: Agreed. If the user is using your app and then receives a phone call they will automatically be pushed to the beginning of the app and lose everything they did.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What exactly would I write if I wanted to display a view controller named "ViewController".

Comment: Would still need to know the navigation structure. Navigation Controller, Split View, Modal, Popover, Custom Segue, or a layered combination of some of the above? It's probably best to post a screen capture of your entire StoryBoard.

Answer (score 1):

Well, every time the app is closed `applicationDidEnterBackground` in your `AppDelegate` is called. You can use that to present your view controller.